# Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList<Student>? This throws a ClassCastException

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization, deserialization, classcastexception

I'm still quite new to Java and need a hand working out how to get around my problem.

I'm attempting to write a method to deserialize an object that I have called `Student`. The method is as follows:

```
   public void readStudentInfo() {
            // Desrializes the student objects into an ArrayList for you to compare against

            try{
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("student.ser");
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

                deserializedStudents = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();

                ois.close();
                fis.close();

            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
                System.out.println("Class not found");
                c.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            for(Student student : deserializedStudents){
                System.out.println(student.toString());
            }
            }
```

The class Student that it works with is as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Class Attributes
    private String studentID;
    private String rankings;
    private char personalityType;
    private String conflict;
    
    private String preferences;

    
    // Class Constructor

    public Student(String ID){
        this.studentID = ID;
    }
    
    public Student(String ID, String grades) {
        this.studentID = ID;
        grades = grades.trim();
        this.rankings = grades;
    }

    public Student(String ID, String ranking,char personality){
        this.studentID = ID;
        this.rankings = ranking;
        this.personalityType = personality;
    }
    
    // Accessor Methods
    public String getStudentID() {
        return this.studentID;
    }

    public String getRankings(){
        return this.rankings;
    }

    public String getPreferences(){
        return this.preferences;
    }

    public char getPersonalityType(){
        return this.personalityType;
    }

    public String getConflict(){
        return this.conflict;
    }

    //Modifier Methods

    public boolean setPreferences(String pref){
        this.preferences = pref;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean setGrades(String grades){
        this.rankings = grades;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean setPersonalityType(char pers){
        this.personalityType = Character.toUpperCase(pers);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean setConflict(String ids){
        this.conflict = ids;
        return true;
    }

    @Override

    public String toString(){
        return studentID + ";" + rankings + ";" + personalityType + ";" + conflict + ";" + preferences; 
    }
    

    
}
```

The ArrayList `deserializedStudents` is initiated at the top of the class like so: `ArrayList<Student> deserializedStudents = new ArrayList<>();`

For some reason the following line of `readStudentInfo()` gives this warning : Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayListJava(16777748)

If I ignore it and run the program regardless, the `readStudentInfo()` method gives the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Student cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList (Student is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base  of loader 'bootstrap')`

Can someone please help me to understand why this is happening? I've tried changing the cast in the following line a few times: `deserializedStudents = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();`. I've also tried changing things around a little where I initiate the ArrayList at the start of the program, but no luck yet.

Clarification: The basic idea here is that I'm trying to deserialize a bunch of Student type objects into an ArrayList so that I can use them again.

Please help!

Comment: Where and what are you exactly writing the data into student.ser

Comment: looks like in your input file there's an instance of student, not a list

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I should probably make an edit to clarify that. My input file has a bunch of serialized student objects. I want to deserialize them into an ArrayList if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you did not serialize a list of Students (which is an own object) but Students one by one. Therefore you should either serialize a list or you should deserialize the Students one by one (by continously calling readObject()).

Try this (using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)):

```
public void readStudentInfo() {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("student.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
        List<Student> deserializedStudents = new ArrayList<>();
        while (fis.available() > 0) {
            deserializedStudents.add((Student) ois.readObject());
        }
        deserializedStudents.foreach(student -> System.out.println(student));
    } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```